# GitHub Pages is showing readme contents

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I've uploaded my files with `index.html` in root folder.

My files: https://github.com/nicks9188/me
Published Page: https://nicks9188.github.io/me/

Earlier it was working. I wanted to make some changes, so I updated files, now 404 error was coming.

I gone through troubleshooting steps, renamed repo/changed `Index.html` to `index.html` cleared cache, waited for few min to see if it is loaded, cleared git cache, changed browser but non of that working. So I'm looking for a resolution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've uploaded my files with `index.html` in root folder.

Actually, you haven't. Your repository contains a file called `index .html` (which can be seen [on your Pages site](https://nicks9188.github.io/me/index%20.html)) in its root folder, but that's not the same as `index.html`.

Rename the file to remove the space between `x` and `.`, commit, and push.